# Revert needlessly altered scrollbars

Tags: gui, lxde, lubuntu, gtk2

Among myself and a few friends, we use the term "improved user experience" in a sarcastic tone, as most of the "improved user experience" we get with some application updates tends to have showstopper bugs or make needless changes that cause problems.

Well, my Lubuntu user experience has just been "improved".

The window scrollbars on my UI have been needlessly altered, mostly on GTK2 applications.  Instead of being the standard pencil-thick bar with an arrow at each end, they are now a thin and narrow strip, and this scrolling widget pops up whenever my mouse gets near it.

[image]

I have no idea where this change has originated or how to revert back to the old style of scroll bars, but it needs to go.  Aside from being an annoying change, I'm finding that in some affected applications (such as Eclipse and Inkscape) I have to be careful when clicking certain areas close to the horizontal scroll bar, or else the scrolling widget will intercept my click.  This is *very* disruptive to my workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars you can revert using this command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

But there are some questions of what version of GTK you are running, so you might want to look at the post I link to.

Comment: That doesn't work with Ubuntu version 15.10.  There are many questions and responses to disabling the scrollbar overlay effect... especially this new form of hiding the scrollbar from sight.  However, none of them work for Eclipse in Ubuntu 15.10.  Is there something in Eclipse that can override this scroll bar alteration?  Not being able to easily see if you have the full scope of the text editor without constantly wiggling the mouse seriously impedes the work flow focus and concentration.